# Mocking indirect dependencies with Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I am new to Jest and unit testing and I am not sure how to handle mocking in case of relatively deep invocation structures. Let's say we have the following app structure:

[image]

Given the grey classes (`axios` and `cache`) are external, 3rd party modules, I need to write unit tests for `Domain.createUser` and `Backend.postUsers` methods.

I have clear that within the `Backend.postUser` tests I need to mock `axios`.

In case of `Domain.createUser`, I would certainly mock `cache`, but I am not sure what to do with its second dependency.

Should I just mock `Backend.postUser` (as a direct dependency) or somehow indirectly mock just `axios` (as external dependency)?

Or both approaches work in different setups?

If so, what criteria should I use to make decision what is the best strategy?

Comment: Your last sentence in post answer to your question. So what's the question?

Comment: @slideshowp2 thank you, I actually figured it out and updated the test a bit.I am actually wondering if both approaches I mentioned make sense at all (especially this indirect mocking)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit testing is all about units. The goal is to find defects in, and verify the functioning of separately testable software units. Usually, unit tests are done in isolation from the rest of the system, meaning that all the dependencies of the unit are mocked.

The size of a unit is entirely up to you. If you decide to mock `axios` when testing `Domain.createUser`, your unit is the combination of `Domain.createUser` and `Backend.postUser`. If you mock `Backend.postUser` instead, you reduce your unit to just `Domain.createUser`. You could even decide to mock nothing, increasing the size of your unit to your entire system.

However, a unit test that covers the entire system doesn't say much. If the unit test fails, the only thing you know is that there's an error in your system. There's no indication as to where in the system that might be. If the unit was much smaller, say, a single function, searching for the bug will be a lot easier. That's why, in practice, you start writing unit tests for the smallest testable component.

In your question you state that you want to test `Domain.createUser`, so that will be your unit. All dependencies of that unit should be mocked, so you'll mock `Backend.postUser`, which will be tested in another test.

If for whatever reason it wouldn't be possible to test `Backend.postUser` separately, it would be better to test `Domain.createUser` and `Backend.postUser` together in a single unit. Then you'll only mock `cache` and `axios`, since those are the direct dependencies of this unit. But usually it's preferred to test both separately.